# how to dynamically change a class using an array with jquery *newbie

Tags: jquery, object

Ok, i have been searching for 2-3 weeks now so I apologize if this has already been answered AND I apologize if I don't get the terminology exactly right. I'm a newbie.

I am creating a budgeting program to help me learn coding. I have 3 columns in an HTML table, and an obj with key/value pairs.

I would like to use the keys in the obj to create classes for my inputs so I can send them all to a database to track/add/do whatever...

```
var obj = { item1=10, item2=20, item3=30}
var getkey = Object.keys(obj)
```

Here is one of the many loops I have tried.

```
for (var i = 0; i < getkey.length, i++) {
var key = getkey[i]
var keyclass = key + "id"
var appendage = "<input id='" + key + "id'" + "name='" + key + "spendinput' type='text' />"
if (i == 0) {
$("#firstrow td:nth-child(3)").append(appendage).addClass(keyclass).removeClass("spendinput")
} else if ($(".spendinput").hasClass(prevkeyclass) == false) {
$(".spendinput").append(appendage).addclass(keyclass)
}

/*Here is my HTML*/
<form method="POST" action="expense.php">
  <table>
   <thead>Current Budget</thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr id="firstrow">
     <td id="utilities"></td>
     <td id="utilitiestotspend" class="spendinput"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="gas"></td>
     <td id="gastotspend" class = "spendinput"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Your object is not setted corectly `var obj = { item1=10, item2=20, item3=30}`. You sould set the pair key value with `:` like `var obj = { item1:10, item2:20, item3:30}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object has wrong syntax. To assign values you use `:`, not `=`.

```
var obj = { item1:10, item2:20, item3:30}
```

One more thing that could be helpful for your future learning is **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)** for Firefox. If you're using Chrome instead, <kbd>F12</kbd> will do the same.
These are very powerful tools that let you inspect/modify (on the fly) HTML, CSS, scripts, network traffic, debug javascript console and much much more. When you get used to it you can't live without it.